# Python AWS- Unicode error Algorithm Error Caused by: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, amazon-sagemaker

I am learning to train and transform using machine learning models on AWS Sagemaker which uses Python 3.6.

I am able to train the Linear Learner model successfully but during transformation, I get an error:

> UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Transform job linear-learner-2019-08-30-11-22-02-821: Failed. Reason: ClientError: See job logs for more information

Which maps to this error in the CloudWatch logs

> Algorithm Error: (caused by UnicodeEncodeError)
>    Caused by: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)

The code which I am using is this
*To Create and train model*

```
import boto3
import sagemaker

sess = sagemaker.Session()

linear = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
                                       role, 
                                       train_instance_count=1, 
                                       train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                                       output_path=output_location,
                                       sagemaker_session=sess)
linear.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim=18,
                           predictor_type='regressor')

linear.fit({'train': s3_train_data})
```

To create input and output S3 locations for test data

```
batch_input ='s3://{}/{}/test/examples'.format(bucket, prefix) # The location of the test dataset   
batch_output = 's3://{}/{}/batch-inference'.format(bucket, prefix) # The location to store the results of the batch transform job

print(batch_input)
print(batch_output)
```

Transform test data

```
housing_test=strat_test_set
housing_test_inputs =full_pipeline.transform (housing_test)
housing_test_inputs=np.float32(housing_test_inputs)
housing_test_labels=strat_test_set['median_house_value'].values
housing_test_labels=np.float32(housing_test_labels)
```

To check consistency of number of features

```
print(housing_test_labels.shape)
print(housing_test_inputs.shape)
print(housing_labels.shape)
print(housing_inputs.shape)
```

Values returned from above are

```
(4128,)
(4128, 18)
(16512,)
(16512, 18)
```

Test data upload to S3

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, housing_test_inputs, housing_test_labels)
buf.seek(0)
key = 'examples'
boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'test', key)).upload_fileobj(buf)
s3_test_data = 's3://{}/{}/test/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, key)
print('uploaded test data location: {}'.format(s3_test_data))
```

Predicting values

```
transformer = linear.transformer(instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge', output_path=batch_output)

transformer.transform(data=batch_input, data_type='S3Prefix', content_type='text/csv', split_type='Line')

transformer.wait()
```

**The error I receive at the console is this-**

> UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         3 transformer.transform(data=batch_input, data_type='S3Prefix', content_type='text/csv', split_type='Line')
>         4 
>   ----> 5 transformer.wait()
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/transformer.py in wait(self)
>       227         """Placeholder docstring"""
>       228         self._ensure_last_transform_job()
>   --> 229         self.latest_transform_job.wait()
>       230 
>       231     def _ensure_last_transform_job(self):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/transformer.py in wait(self)
>       344 
>       345     def wait(self):
>   --> 346         self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_transform_job(self.job_name)
>       347 
>       348     @staticmethod
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in wait_for_transform_job(self, job, poll)
>      1050         """
>      1051         desc = _wait_until(lambda: _transform_job_status(self.sagemaker_client, job), poll)
>   -> 1052         self._check_job_status(job, desc, "TransformJobStatus")
>      1053         return desc
>      1054
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
>      1077                 ),
>      1078                 allowed_statuses=["Completed", "Stopped"],
>   -> 1079                 actual_status=status,
>      1080             )
>      1081
>
> UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Transform job linear-learner-2019-08-30-11-22-02-821: Failed. Reason: ClientError: See job logs for more information

Can somebody please suggest what is the root cause of this error and how to fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of the `locale` and `locale charmap` commands, run from your terminal.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I am using AWS Sagemaker online environment. How do I execute locale and locale charmap commands?